# Hide display if empty data

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'd like to display info when there is info in my description.
I need to hide the whole thing when there's no info

```
{if !empty($product.description-short) }
<span class="label" style="text-decoration:underline">
{l s='Information:' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</span>
{$product.description_short nofilter}
{/if}
```

Problem : Even when there are info, nothing will display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if statement you check for description-short and try to display description_short.
Should be:

```
{if !empty($product.description_short) }
<span class="label" style="text-decoration:underline">
{l s='Information:' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</span>
{$product.description_short nofilter}
{/if}
```

Comment: It happens... after a while, we get "code blindness". that's why a little rest, or getting someone else help is a good idea.